# How do I find my direction of travel in a potential using Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, gradient, physics

EDIT:
My issue is I'm trying to do a more complex elliptical potential and it's not giving me anything. I'm trying to do collision detection via potentials as two objects A and B repel each other (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9805244.pdf).

The position vectors and direction vectors are numpy arrays and v_B, dt are scalars. The below is what I want to do to get the gradient over the 2d space.

The potential is elliptical as well, hence the weird expression for b:

```
xs = ys = np.arange(0, 50, 1)
x, y = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)

r_AB = A.position - B.position
b = 0.5*np.sqrt( (np.linalg.norm(r_AB)+np.linalg.norm(r_AB -v_B*dt*B_direction))**2 - (v_B*dt)**2)

f_AB= -np.gradient(V(b))
```

Here, V is essentially e^-b. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Could you please add what you've already tried to get the gradient? Probably you can use `np.gradient` somehow.

Comment: I achieved a gradient with previous code, but I don't know how to do a gradient where the b function contains constants. For example I got it working if you replaced b with b= x^2 + y^2, but I need to do the gradient based on the position vectors.